# How to add multiple array items as HTML content?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to extract some words from a string of text, insert every character of that words inside a span element and then replace the extracted words with the span elements. I have been able to convert characters into span elements but I can't figure out how to replace the extracted words with the span elements without deleting the other words.

```
<h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
```

```
const title = document.querySelector('.title');

// Extract required words and split them into single character
const firstWord = title.textContent.split(' ').filter(wrd => wrd.startsWith('L')).toString().split('');
const secondWord = title.textContent.split(' ').filter(wrd => wrd.startsWith('a')).toString().split('');

// Return a new array with every character inside a span element
const spanCharacters = arr => {
    return arr.map(char => {
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = char;
        return span;
    });
};

const spanFirstWord = spanCharacters(firstWord);
// return [<span>L</span>, <span>o</span>, <span>r</span>, <span>e</span>, <span>m</span>]

const spanSecondWord = spanCharacters(secondWord);
// return [<span>a</span>, <span>m</span>, <span>e</span>, <span>t</span>]
```

Now, what I'd like to do is this:

```
<!-- before -->
<h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

<!-- after -->
<h1 class="title"><span>L</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>e</span><span>m</span> ipsum dolor sit <span>a</span><span>m</span><span>e</span><span>t</span></h1>
```

How could I replace the extracted words with the generated spans keeping the other words where they are?

Comment: Where you extract the words make sure you store the remainder as well, then stitch them back in at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
const ttl=document.querySelector("h1.title"),
      txt=ttl.textContent;

function spanifyWords(beginsArr,txt){
 return txt.split(" ").map(w=>{
  if (beginsArr.some(b=>w.startsWith(b))) 
    w="<span>"+w.split("").join("</span><span>")+"</span>";
  return w
 }).join(" ");
}

ttl.innerHTML=spanifyWords(["a","L"],txt);
```

```css
span {color: green; border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
```

Instead of `. filter()`-ing I use `.map()`to go through every word. Inside the callback function I check with `.some()` relative to some `beginsArr` whether the current word starts with one of the characters in question. If so, I "spanify" the word otherwise I return the word as is. At the end I stitch everything together again with `.join()`.